# Reference project B without C

Tags: c#

I have three projects A, B and C. These are connected together like so:

> A -> B -> C

If project C has a base like so:

```
public class CBaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and project B has an inheriting class like so:

```
public class BInheritingClass : CBaseClass
{

}
```

How can I access BInheritingClass.Name in project A without it giving me the following error:

> The type 'CBaseClass' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ProjectC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

when I do not have A referencing C.

To clarify I want project A to reference B that uses things from C without A referencing C.

Is this possible?

Comment: why do you care? It's not a difficult task to add a project reference.

Comment: @ADyson Because I want Project A to be stupid of C which I think is quite reasonable

Comment: you may want that, but as the answers show, it isn't possible. Code in project A needs to know how CBaseClass is defined in order to use that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to avoid referencing C, because `CBaseClass` is part of the public interface of `BInheritingClass`. Project A has no way of knowing the full definition of `BInheritingClass` without knowing `CBaseClass`.

If you want to avoid this, you have to avoid inheritance and use composition - make `BInheritedClass` *not* inherit `CBaseClass`, and instead contain it internally, not exposing it as a parameter or public member. Only that way can it remain an implementation detail of B, not part of its contract.

Comment: Apart from creating a wrapper is there no way to essentially embed `ProjectC` inside of `ProjectB`?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder You can pull some tricks and jump through hoops and embed ProjectC in ProjectB - but how is that different than just adding a reference to ProjectC?

Answer (score 2):

If project `A` in any way uses anything defined public in project `C`, you need to reference `C`. In your example, project A defines a class based on something defined in C, so you need to reference C.

---

**You updated your question**
This answer is still true: As `B` defines a `BInheritingClass` based on `CBaseClass` defined in `C`, `A` needs to know `C` if it wants to use the class in `B`, otherwise it would not know the "base features" of `CBaseClass` and thus can not determine the features of `BInheritingClass`.

If you don't want `A` to "know" `C`, you may not expose anything from `C` through `B` to `A`. Composition is one solution to the problem, but this essentially means you need to remodel the public interface of `CBaseClass` in `BNoLongerInheritingClass`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a class defined in an assembly you did not reference. 
(Except for dynamic loading with reflection). Maintaining this reference hierarchy is exactly why tools like NuGet where developed.